# Bootstrap 4 text-left class strange behaviour

Tags: forms, bootstrap-4, inline, text-alignment

I tried using `'text-left'` on a `<div>` and found that it doesn't work.
So I set up the simplest example I can think of:

```
<form>
    <div class="col-12 form-inline">
        <label class="col-10 text-left" style="background-color:powderblue;">TestLabel</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

and I tested it on https://www.codeply.com/
The result is: it's working only on `sm` screen size.

width 360:

[image]

but on 768 and above:

[image]

And my question is: am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in Bootstrap?

Comment: There shouldn't be a col-10 inside a col-12. *"content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows"* Create a codeply snippet that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the flexform behaviour of **form-inline**.

You have to use **justify-content-start** instead of **text-left**

```
<form>
    <div class="col-12 form-inline">
        <label class="col-10 justify-content-start" style="background-color:powderblue;">TestLabel</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

And don't use cols inside a col without a row.